# Owl Carrousel scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, swap, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel and I am trying to swap a slide to the next slide on clicking a button named "Vote Now" in owl carousel" but there is one issue when I click on 2nd DOT and click on 4th position of "Vote Now" button it swap to 3rd position of slide, its ok. But 4th position of slide goes hidden I want to its just scroll one slide backward and also visible 4th position of slide.

[Here is my fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/b8qx6jjt/9/) Can anyone help me?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var animating = false;
    $('#container').on('click', '.click', function() {
        var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div.ddd'),
        prevDiv = clickedDiv.prev(),
        distance = clickedDiv.offset().left - prevDiv.offset().left;
        if (prevDiv.length) {
           animating = true;
           $.when(clickedDiv.animate({
             left: -distance
           }, 1000),
          prevDiv.animate({
            left: distance
          }, 1000)).done(function() {
             prevDiv.css('left', '0px');
             clickedDiv.css('left', '0px');
             clickedDiv.insertBefore(prevDiv);
             animating = false;
          });
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// owl carousel
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = $('.owl-carousel');
  slider.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: false,
    center: false,
    margin: 10,
    callbacks: true,
    URLhashListener: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash',
    touchDrag: false,
    mouseDrag: false
  });
  $(".swap").click(function() {
    slider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
  });
})
```